# Algorithm to break non-standardized intervals into five minute periods - Python / SAS

Tags: python, loops, sas, intervals

Say I have an input (22:00 - 43:00).  From it I want to create the following:

```
begin = 22:00 end = 25:00
begin = 25:00 end = 30:00
begin = 30:00 end = 35:00
begin = 35:00 end = 40:00
begin = 40:00 end = 43:00
```

How would one use a loop to get both the new begin date and the new end date efficiently with a minimum of code (including the partial first and last interval)?  The tricky part is that I need the solution to work if given intervals like (20:00 - 43:00) or (22:00 - 40:00) or simply (20:00 - 40:00).

Will be implementing this in SAS on date-time variables, but would be grateful for an algorithm in Python since I know there are more users on SO.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SAS solution. 5 minutes corresponds to 300 seconds and datetime in SAS are measured in seconds.  The variables are represented in datetime but if you want only time you can use the timepart() function.

```
*Generate some sample data;
data have;
time_s = dhms('01Jan2014'd, 0, 24, 0);
time_e = dhms('01Jan2014'd, 0, 40, 0);
format time: datetime20.;
run;

proc print data=have;
run;

*Calculate intervals;
data want;
set have;

time_start=time_s;
time_end=round(time_s+150, 300);

output;

do while (time_end<time_e);
    time_start=time_end;
    time_end+300;

    if time_end>time_e then time_end=time_e;
    output;
end;

format time: datetime20.;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

And the output:

```
                  Obs              time_start                time_end

                   1       01JAN2014:00:22:00      01JAN2014:00:25:00
                   2       01JAN2014:00:25:00      01JAN2014:00:30:00
                   3       01JAN2014:00:30:00      01JAN2014:00:35:00
                   4       01JAN2014:00:35:00      01JAN2014:00:40:00
                   5       01JAN2014:00:40:00      01JAN2014:00:43:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, however this solution does not get the first partial (22 - 25) or the last partial (40-43) interval, in my example.  Or 24-25 in your example.

Comment: The last interval was correct, but the first was not, for some reason I was reading it as rounded.  Anyways, I corrected that at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has the [`intnx()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000212700.htm) for incrementing by date and time intervals. This approach uses `intnx()` alongside the [`intck()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212868.htm) to count the intervals and the [`minutes5` interval](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0g056g35ez8son1sfavozh0lfb3.htm#n1d3z2e1f8u8drn1j70702vf4q3h) for alignment. Additionally, the [`ifn()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002604573.htm) is used to evaluate whether to use the start and end values.

```
data have;
    start = dhms("01Jan1960"d, 0, 23, 0);
    end = dhms("01Jan1960"d, 0, 51, 0);
run;
data want;
    set have;
    /* Get number of intervals to loop over */
    max = intck("minute5", start, end - 1) + 1;
    do i = 1 to max;
        /* Offset start date by the loop number of intervals */
        time_start = ifn(i = 1, start, intnx("minute5", start, i - 1 , "b"));
        time_end = ifn(i = max, end, intnx("minute5", start, i, "b"));
        output;
    end;
    format time: datetime.;
    keep time:;
run;
```